# URL is getting append while clicking an hyperlink php

Tags: php

I am writing a small webpage in php . while clicking an hyperlink the hyperlink is getting appended

```
function get_url($ff) {
  $q = isset($_REQUEST['query']) ? $_REQUEST['query'] : NULL;
  return "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443) ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'?query=' .$q. '&bw' . '=' . $ff ;
} 

 <li><a href="<?php print get_url('exampl');?>">example</a></li>
```

This outputs url like

```
http://example.com/test/?query=search&bw=test.
```

while clicking next time i get

```
http://example.com/test/?query=search&bw=test?query=search&bw=test.
```

Comment: If you are replacing the query values then why do you have to check with isset ? you can remve $q=issset line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
return "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443) ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'?query=' .$q. '&bw' . '=' . $ff ;
```

to

```
return "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443) ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .'?query=' .$q. '&bw' . '=' . $ff ;
```